# Returning a line of txt.-file that has a word with more than 6 characters and starts with "A" in Python

Tags: python, txt

I have a task to accomplish in Python with only one sentence:
I need to return lines of my txt-file that include words which have more than 6 characters and start with the letter "A".

My code is the following:

```
[line for line in open('test.txt') if line.split().count('A') > 6]
```

I am not sure how to implement another command in order to say that my word starts with "A" and has to have more than 6 characters. That is the furthest I could do. I thank you for your time.

Greetings

Comment: Is there a reason `startswith()` has not been brought up? Obviously this is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split up your for loop so that it's not a list comprehension, to make it easier to understand what's going on. Once you do that, it should be clearer what you're missing so you can assemble it back into a list comprehension.

```py
lines = []

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:   # this line reads each line in the file
        add_line = False
        for word in line.split():
            if (word.startswith('A') and len(word) > 6):
                 add_line = True
                 break
        if (add_line):
            lines.append(line)
```

This roughly translates to

```py
[line for line in open('test.txt', 'r') if any(len(word) > 6 and word.startswith('A') for word in line.split())]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should break each line and compare each word separately

`[line for line in open('test.txt') if len([word for word in line.split(' ') if word[0].lower() == 'a' and len(word)> 6]) > 0]`